# NLog structured logging with duplicate hole names

Tags: c#, nlog, structured-logging

I'm trying to figure it out what is a correct behaviour for capturing properties with duplicate hole names according [message templates syntax](https://messagetemplates.org/) which is implemented in the NLog.

Let's look an example.

1. Record to console with duplicate hole names but the count of parameters less than count of names.

   ```
   // Targets where to log to: File and Console
   var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("logconsole");
   config.AddRule(global::NLog.LogLevel.Debug, global::NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, logconsole);
   // Apply config           
   NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
   NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("A").Info("hello from {a} {b} {a}", 1, 2);
   ```

The output is

> 2020-05-26 09:47:37.5013|INFO|A|hello from {a} {b} {a}

There is no any substitutions!

2. Record to console with duplicate hole names with the same count of parameters.

   ```
   // Targets where to log to: File and Console
   var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("logconsole");
   config.AddRule(global::NLog.LogLevel.Debug, global::NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, logconsole);
   // Apply config           
   NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
   NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("A").Info("hello from {a} {b} {a}", 1, 2, 3);
   ```

The output is

> 2020-05-26 09:49:53.1436|INFO|A|hello from 1 2 3

Substitutions were apply.

So, I am expected to see substitutions in the first case, but there is no. Is it a correct behaviour in the NLog regarding [message templates syntax](https://messagetemplates.org/)?

**I have checked the behaviour in the first case for Serilog. It does substitutions.**

Comment: Why do think that this is correct `Info("hello from {a} {b} {a}", 1, 2);` and will work?

Comment: Some NLog guides might be helpful https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I don't know, it seems to me that it’s just logical. That a = 1 and b = 2. and substitution should take a place. Right now I have checked the behaviour of serilog provider, it does substitutions in this case. Now this behavior of NLog seems doubly strange to me

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Curious why you are interested in using invalid message templates? In what situations is that useful? Believe Microsoft-ILogger (MEL) throws exceptions when given invalid number of place-holders.

Comment: @RolfKristensen, it is difficult to say in which cases it may be useful. I am just implementing a structured logging layer in my application, and have considered different cases. And stumbled upon this case. it interested me because the behavior looks illogical. So, I decided to ask. I just try to find out answer if I don’t understand something. May be it will be better if NLog throws exception in this case too than just silence.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Not many are interesting in optimizing for invalid cases. But you are more than welcome to create a pull-request to improve the behavior of the NLog Message Formatter when given invalid input. https://github.com/NLog/NLog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct behavior according to NLog documentation - [How to use structured logging](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging) states

> The Names of the parameters should be unique

Though *Capturing Rules* at [messagetemplates.org](https://messagetemplates.org/) do not put such a restriction to parameters:

> If any of the property names are non-numeric, then all arguments are
>   captured by matching left-to-right with holes in the order in which
>   they appear

NLog has its own interpretation of left-to-right matching - if the count of properties does not match the number of arguments, then format not considered a valid structured message template (Check [ParseMessageTemplate](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/dev/src/NLog/MessageTemplates/MessageTemplateParameters.cs) method). Which gives you two expected results

```
Logger.Info("{User} {Value}", "Bob", 42); // "Bob" 42
Logger.Info("{User} {Value} {User}", "Bob", 42); // invalid template
```

And one not expected (but NLog has warned you to use unique properties):

```
Logger.Info("{User} {Value} {User}", "Bob", 42, "Joe"); // "Bob" 42 "Joe"
```

If you expect to get `"Joe" 42 "Joe"` on the last example, then you can use [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or use numeric property names in message template `"{0} {1} {0}"` (not recommended).

Comment: Thank you, Sergey. Now I know about this architectural restriction of NLog.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Think the only architectural decision made by NLog is not to explode in your face when given invalid input. And focus on giving best performance for valid message templates, and avoid introducing overhead for handling invalid message templates (Avoid any overhead for scanning for right place-holder-value)

Comment: @RolfKristensen, I understand why this is done. I have no complaints about this. I absolutely agree with you that performance is more important. But now I know about this case.

Comment: @RolfKristensen but I have to note, I conducted benchmarks and compared NLog with Serilog, Serilog handles this case as I have mentioned. At the same time the performance of both log provider of writing structured logs is comparable

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Always interested in benchmarks. Is it a benchmark that you can share on github?

Comment: @RolfKristensen, I knew that I have to answer about them. Not yet, hands do not reach to do it. 
But I want to share them later, because I didn't find comparing NLog and Serilog in the www.  I found only it https://github.com/imanushin/nlog-log4net-performance-comparison. It compares nlog and log4net, but it is not interested because the winner is known advance. :)